# How to surround a string that is '+', or '-' with quotes?

Tags: php, string, match

I am trying to detect whether a string is `*`, `/`, `+`, or `-` and if it is, changing that string to be `"+"`, `"-"`, etc. (basically adding double quotes to each end of the original string). I need to do this because I need to prepare these strings to be input into a python script or else the syntax will be wrong.

This is what I've tried so far:

```php
$input = "+";

if ($input=="*" || $input="/" || $input=="+" || $input=="-") {
    $input = '"' . $input . '"';
}

echo $input;
```

The output of this is always this:

```
"1"
```

How would I accomplish what I'm trying to do? That would be an output, in this case of:

```
"+"
```

Comment: Change `$input="/"` to `$input=="/"`

Comment: Wow how did I not see this

Comment: protip, use: `in_array($input, ['*', '/', '+', '-']))`

Answer (score 2):

Question answered by catcon in the comments, just had to change `$input="/"` to `$input=="/"`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this with str_replace,

```
$input = "+";
$result = str_replace(["*","/","+","-"],['"*"','"/"','"+"','"-"'],$input);
print_r($result);
```